# Scanpy Matplotlib ax objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scanpy

I'm using scanpy/python to analyze some single-cell RNA-seq data. I want to use `sc.pl.umap(show= False)` in order to make ax objects, edit them, and combine them accordingly. I can get a single umap to work, but I can't get multiple umaps to combine together in subplots as one object. Could someone help me figure this out?

For example, I have two dataset and I want to combine their umaps together into one object instead of having to align them manually in powerpoint afterwards.

Thanks

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create the Figure object yourself first, and pass the 'ax' argument to the umap function. The documentation states this "Only works if plotting a single component"

something like:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
sc.pl.umap(show=False, ax=axes[0])
```